# Django Rest API Type error for positional argument

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django fires me this error and i am not getting why..

```
TypeError at /api/v1/article

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/article
Django Version:     2.2.2
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is my serializer class:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'body', 'category']
```

these are my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.TextField()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And this is my view

```
class ArticleListCreateGet(ListAPIView, CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

and this my url

```
path('api/v1/article', views.ArticleListCreateGet, name='article'),
```

I am not getting whats wrong with my code, can anyone tell me why i am seeing above error?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `views.ArticleListCreateGet.as_view()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is referring to `views.ArticleListCreateGet` which is a class based view, not a function.

Try `views.ArticleListCreateGet.as_view()` in your path and see what happens.